# how to add explicit equation number in aligned environment?

Tags: align, tags

I have looked at all related questions and not able to find solution.
I have to use `aligned` and since `aligned` does not support `tag`, how would one add an explicit equation number?

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} 
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
$
\begin{aligned}
x &= y \sin(x)  \\
  &= \cos(x)    %How to number this line? \tag{3} does not work
\end{aligned}
$}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I do not want an automatic equation number on the `equation` itself. But I want to add a specific equation number on one of the equations inside `aligned` itself.

I tried to do it by hand, but I do not know the amount of `hspace` to add to make the equation number show up at the right edge of the page as what happens automatically when using `tag`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}    
\begin{equation*} 
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
$
\begin{aligned}
x &= y \sin(x)  \\
  &= \cos(x)   \hspace*{20pt} \text{(3)}  %how to know how much space?
\end{aligned}
$}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any suggestions how to do the above.

Comment: lines inside `aligned` cannot be numbered. Numbered can be environment in whole, i.e. equation. However, use of `align` which enable desired numbering of equation, doesn't work with `\adjustbox`.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, I know all of this. That is why I asked. I have to use `adjustbox`.  That is why I had to use `aligned`. But I also want to add an equation number.  Do you know how to use `hspace` to add correct amount of space to end of `\textwidth`? If so I can do it by hand as above., But do not know how much space to add to do it manually.

Comment: The simplest solution is not to use `\adjustbox`. It is (i) typographically very fragile (ii) you have only problems with hackering of its contents, by which you like to restore basic features of `align` environment.

Comment: @Zarko Ok, thanks for suggestion. But I have to use adjusbox for other reasons. I'll wait a little more and if there is no solution, will delete this question in this case. No problem.

Comment: scaling the equations is horrible, but if you must, you can/should still use `align` not `aligned` just put it in a `\parbox` to get back to vertical mode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the advice. If you could post an answer showing how write the MWE I have using `align` and with `\parbox` that will be great. I do not know the right syntax and where to put this `\parbox` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too big for a comment ...

Forcing tag to text border nullifies the effect of `\adjustbox`. For example, compare the following  examples:

[image]

Both give the very same result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,adjustbox}
%% Automatic math-mode versions of l, r, and c column types:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}  
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$\displaystyle}r<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle{}}c<{{}$}}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <-- important
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X RCL >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
      & x & = & y \sin(x)  &     \\
      &   & = &   \cos(x)  & (3)  
  \end{tabularx}% <-- this comment symbol is needed
  }
\]

\begin{align}
    x & = y \sin(x) \notag  \\
      & =   \cos(x) \tag{3}
\end{align}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your code so that the `=` symbols line up vertically in the `tabularx`-based example. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico, thank you. In rush I wasn't careful enough :-(